# DSC-P52 digital camera power button

Tags: repair

I have searched and asked in a lot of forums for a long time but my problem with this camera is still there.

Is there anything that I can do to fix it?

My problem is the socket for the power and shutter button is broke off and 2 solder pad.

I think that circuit is multilayer because I can't find where it comes from.

I have solderer some jumper wire and 2 missing pad is unable to be found.
Here is some Image(sorry if it too big):
[image: The image with 2 wires representing 2 missing pads]

[image: The red and green wire is the same as the next image]

[image: .]

I hope this is enough information to fix my camera. Thank you!

Image of the missing solder pad:
[image: Immage of the missing pad]

Comment: what missing pads are you talking about? ... how do you know that pads are missing?

Comment: your soldering looks very sloppy ... the wires may be shorting ... are the wires insulated? ... if they are, then did you remove the insulation from the soldered ends?

Comment: my wire is insulated and removed the end insulation before soldered,
the missing pad is hard to see on the image
I have posted a image you can see up there